# Re-running ArcGIS Desktop geoprocessing tool from Toolbox history?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.6

According to the ArcGIS Desktop documentation on [Viewing tool execution history](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/history-log-files.htm):

> This historical information is very useful for determining how data
>   was created and can be used to rerun a process.

If I restart ArcMap 10.6 I have lost all previous geoprocessing tasks in the results window.

How can I re-run a logged geoprocessing task using the information stored in the log file other than doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the map that you run the Geoprocessing tools in. When you come back to that project later on, you will find the gegoprocessing tools are still there and you can run any of them again.

As you can see below, I run many geoprocessing tools last week and because I saved the mxd file, I can still come back to it and re-run again the same tools.

You need to open the result window to access these tools from `Geoprocessing Menu -> Results` in ArcMap.

[image]

Comment: You could choose the time to keep the result in the geoprocessing option menu (from never to always).

Comment: but be aware that it could made your mxd really huge making it really long to load

Comment: @J.R thanks for the additional information, but I did not change the default time in geoprocessing which is 2 weeks. The speed is still okay for me.

Comment: Thanks. I have to save the project then. I though I could maybe restart the tools from the xml logs.